# this is my simple php script for login, i cannot POST values from database

Tags: php, mysql, post

this is the whole php script. nothing happens after connecting to database

```
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost:3306", "xyz", "xyz", "xyz");
echo "connected to the database";

if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
```

this is the php script after the form is connected to database.

```
if (isset($_POST['submit']))
 //program never enters this
{
    if (isset($_POST['id']) && isset($_POST['name']) && ($_POST['pass'])) {
        $i_d = $_POST['id'];
        $username = $_POST['uname'];
        $password = $_POST['pass'];
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM emp WHERE ID='$i_d' and User_Name='$username' and  Password='$password' and active=1";
        $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql) or die(mysqli_error());
        $count = mysqli_num_rows($result);
        if ($count == 1) {
            echo "You are logged in";
        } else {
            echo "Login Failed";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Issues with this code (but not related to your problem): You have plain text passwords in your database and you are open for SQL injection attacks. Look up how prepared statements work and store the password as a hash in the database.

Comment: You have both `$_POST['name']` and `$_POST['uname']`.

Comment: Post a var_dump of `$_POST`

Comment: yes, i corrected the uname error 
but its still not working

Comment: Try to remove single quotes of $i_d from query since its a number and try to echo $count. Check if your are getting any count or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
/* ESTABLISH CONNECTION */

$con=mysqli_connect("localhost:3306","xyz","xyz","xyz");
echo "connected to the database";

if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}   


/* this is the php script after the form is connected to database. */

   if (isset($_POST['submit'])) /* IF SUBMIT BUTTON IS CLICKED. MAKE SURE THE NAME OF YOUR SUBMIT BUTTON IS 'submit' */
    { 
    if (!empty($_POST['id']) && !empty($_POST['name']) && !empty($_POST['pass'])){ /* YOU FORGOT THE THIRD CONDITION ON THIS PART*/

/* USE AT LEAST REAL ESCAPE FUNCTION TO PREVENT SQL INJECTION */

      $i_d = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['id']); 
      $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['uname']);
      $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['pass']);

      $sql = "SELECT * FROM emp WHERE ID='$i_d' AND User_Name='$username' AND Password='$password' AND active='1'"; /* YOUR QUERY. MAKE SURE YOU HAVE YOUR PUT THE COLUMN NAMES CORRECTLY. */
      $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql); /* EXECUTE QUERY */

      $count = mysqli_num_rows($result); /* COUNT THE RESULT OF YOUR QUERY */ 
      if ($count == 1){
      echo "You are logged in";
      }

      else { echo "Login Failed"; } 

    } /* END OF IF NOT EMPTY SUBMITTED DATA */

   } /* END OF IF ISSET SUBMIT */
```

### Note:

- I have put comments `/* */` on the changes I have made on your code.
- You forgot your IF condition for your `$_POST['pass']` variable.
- Use *at least* *mysqli_real_escape_string function* to prevent ***SQL injections***.
- Make sure you have put the right *column names* from your `emp` *table* on your query.

Comment: i used your script and corrected where i was wrong, i got the error "Warning: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in C:\wamp\www\Doc.php on line 34"

Answer (score 0):

Try to echo `$_POST['submit']`,`$_POST['id']`,`$_POST['name']` and `$_POST['pass']` and check whether you are getting data or not.

Answer (score 0):

```
print_r($_POST);
```

put this out side of  **if (isset($_POST['submit'])){}** 
and see are you getting **[submit] => Submit** in post array().
check name of your submit button it must be **input name="submit"**